# How to borrow from zeroes in binary subtraction (no complements)b?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary

I know you can use complements to subtract, but I want to subtract these two binary numbers without that. I am unsure of how to borrow numbers from zero, check it out:

1000000
-101100

How do I subtract these two binary numbers?

This page borrows from zeros, but doesn't really explain it:
http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/pm/sub.html

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Without using complements, subtraction in binary is just like decimal subtraction: $a-b=-(b-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just figured it out.

You can go all the way to the left and cut the 1 backwards.

Thing is, if you have 10 in binary = 2. That means you can cut it down to 1 and then move another 1 to the right. If you keep doing this, you can subtract the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in decimal subtraction, if the digit you want to borrow from is 0, you borrow 1 from the next digit.  If *that* digit is 0, you go on to the next, and so on.